# Secure and private web browser for OS X

Tags: osx, web-browser, security

Normally I am a Linux user and I am using [Palemoon](http://www.palemoon.org/) as my primary internet browser there. Previous to that I was a sworn [Firefox Nightly](https://nightly.mozilla.org/) user but since Microsoft has intervened and Mozilla decided to ruin Firefox by introducing Australis. Somehow I survived it when I switched to Palemoon, which still sports the old good Firefox look with somewhat optimized performance. [Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome/) was never an option for me since it's basically built for Google to spy on you.

Now I am unfortunately "forced" to use a an Apple MacBook Pro with OS X. Palemoon is not available for OS X. I've tried Komodo's browsers but they are for Windows only. And no, Tor is not an option for me too.

Can somebody suggest me some secure and customizable browser, based either on Chromium or Firefox or something else?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "secure"? Secure defaults (is there any browser that claims not to have these?), audited code, good history of fixing security issues, good history of having only few security issues, certain encryption features, certain add-ons, …?

Comment: I stopped reading at "What exactly do you mean with secure". Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at [Opera](http://www.opera.com/).

- Multi-platform including OS-X
- Pleasant to use
- includes PDF viewer
- claims good security
- lots of customisation options

I have not heard any moans about the security as I have with IE & Co.